# Converting "Textarea" object from iPython wigdet to a list or iterable array

Tags: list, widget, ipython, textarea, iterable

I have created several Textarea widgets in Jupyter/Python in order to capture some string inputs.

In the highlighted in yellow that you can see below, the idea is that the user puts a list of numbers here (copied from Excel) and later I need to convert this text into a list or an array that contains these numbers (an iterable object). I have no idea how to do this. See:

[image]

When I print the type of this object that is called "plus" I get this:

```
print(type(plus))
<class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Textarea'>
```

But, I am expecting to have something like this:

```
plus = [454, 555]
```

Can I bounce some ideas off you to get this?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ipywidget in general, you can observe its change and get its value as following.

```
foo = widgets.Textarea()
# to get the value
foo.value
# to do something on value change
def bar(change):
    print(change.new)
foo.observe(bar, names=['value'])
```

You will then have to format the string you get from the products value, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Hope this helps